# Device Token NULL

Tags: ios, notifications, push, token, device

I have a strange issue that I cannot replicate on my own. Some of my users are returning blank (or null) device tokens for Apple Push Notification. Its probably happening on 5% of users.
Any one have had the same issue or know something about this.

My Code for getting Device Token is:

```
- (void)application: (UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: (NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
    NSString* tokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""] ;

    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setObject:tokenString forKey:@"deviceToken"];

}

- (void)application: (UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: (NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be manipulating the device token in that way, and especially not using the `description` method, which is a debugging aid and not a *convert-to-string* operator.

From the [`UIApplicationDelegate` reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:):

> *deviceToken*
>
> A token that identifies the device to APS. The token is an
>   **opaque** data type because that is the form that the provider needs to
>   submit to the APS servers when it sends a notification to a device.
>   The APS servers require a binary format for performance reasons.
>
> The size of a device token is 32 bytes.
>
> Note that the device token is different from the uniqueIdentifier
>   property of UIDevice because, for security and privacy reasons, it
>   must change when the device is wiped.

Store the device token in binary form.

Comment: By the way I got the answer. Those users were using Jailbreak phones :)

Comment: @ArsalanHaider My answer still stands; you have no hope of recreating the device token using your code.

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
    NSUInteger devicetokenlen=[deviceToken length];
    char* devicetoken=(char*)malloc(devicetokenlen+1);
    memcpy(devicetoken,[deviceToken bytes],devicetokenlen);
    devicetoken[devicetokenlen]=0;
    //...
    free(devicetoken);
```

The flaw is You cannot assume token always to be 32 bytes long.
It may change some day. So You don't know size of token when passing it somewhere via NULL terminated char array. For example, token may contain NULL character. So its preferred to convert token binary data using base64 or hex or something similar or pass it in binary data + size form.